# Unable to understand clone

Tags: java, object, cloning, cloneable

I have a simple program to clone a object , I googled the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException:"  but need your help to understand the error, why am I not able to get clone of obj1?

```
public class Test{
int a;
int b;
public Test(int a , int b){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    }
public static void main(String[]args) throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    Test obj1=new Test(2, 4);
    Test obj2=(Test) obj1.clone();
       }
 }
```

Comment: I advise you not to use the clone paradigm, it is very hard to get right. Do yourself a favor and switch to copy constructors. See also: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because the class `Test` doesn't implement the `Cloneable` interface. As stated in the [API specs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29),

> if the class [..] does not implement the interface Cloneable, then a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown.

To fix, try something like:

```
public class Test implements Cloneable { 
  ...
}
```

Since the `Cloneable` interface declares no methods (it's called a *marker* interface, just like `Serializable`), there's nothing more to do. The instances of your `Test` class can now be cloned.

However, the default cloning mechanism (ie, that of `Object`) might not be exactly what you are looking for, and you might want to override the `clone()` method. The default is to make a *shallow copy*, that is, you will get a new, distinct instance of your class, but the fields of both instances will refer to the same objects! For example:

```
class C1 {
  Object o;
}
class C2 implements Cloneable {
  C1 c1;
}

... main ... {
  C2 c2 = new C2();
  c2.c1 = new C1();
  c2.c1.o = new Object();
  C2 c2clone = c2.clone();
  System.out.println(c2 == c2clone); // prints false
  System.out.println(c2.c1 == c2clone.c1); // prints true
  c2.c1.o = new Object(); // modified both c2 and c2clone!!!
```

The last line will modify both c2 and c2clone because both point to the same instance of c1. If you want the last line to modify only c2, then you have to make what we call a *deep copy*.

Comment: Yes it worked thanks, please answer this,  if we implemented Cloneable interface, which of the methods in Cloneable are we defining/overriding in our class?

Comment: The `Cloneable` interface has no methods. It is just a marker, just like `Serializable`.

Comment: @helloMaga: none. `Cloneable` has no methods. As @cmv mentioned, it's a pure marker interface (i.e. it's existence allone has a meaning, it doesn't force you to implement some methods). Another common marker interface is `Serializable`. Marker interfaces are not usually considered to be a very good design, but they do exist.

Comment: If there is no method declared in an interface why will any developer need it ? why is it in Java Docs? why should we even implement it? If its something like - interface MarkerExampl {}, then I feel its waste of space and time. Please educate me.

Comment: The point of marker interfaces is to make it clear that the object has been designed to be cloneable (or serializable, etc). Suppose you have an object that holds a socket connection. What would be the meaning of cloning it? Would both instances share the same connection? Would the new instance have a new, indepentend connection? If you make this hypothetic class Cloneable, you are stating that you have thought about all the implications of making it Cloneable. That's the (often missed) point of marker interfaces.

Comment: @Bruno, I love stackoverflow, and I love the way people share knowledge, thanks a lot to all of you who helped me realize importance of these methods.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement Cloneable. It's a marker interface.

Your program should be

```
    public class Test implements Cloneable{
         //rest of the program
    }
```

Comment: if we implemented Cloneable interface, which of the methods in Cloneable are we defining/overriding in our class?

Comment: Cloneable is a marker interface. It doesn't have any methods.

Comment: If there is no method declared in an interface why will any developer need it ? why is it in Java Docs? why should we even implement it? If its something like - interface MarkerExampl {}, then I feel its waste of space and time. Please educate me.